# How to use php echo to display user input multiple times

Tags: php, html

I need someone to help me with php guides on how i can echo every user input to the screen...

Example:
Html

```
<form action"bot.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Php Code

```php
<?php
//request name from form
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];

//create function
function msg()
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    echo "$username";
    echo "\r\n";
}

//echo input to screen
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    msg();
}
```

If I click submit button it will display my input text to the screen, that's fine, If I input another username click on submit button again to display under my previous output to screen...Instead PHP overide my previous output with new username submitted..

Will be glad if anyone can help

Comment: You want to keep a record of all the names submitted? One simple solution for demo purposes would be to keep an array of names in the Session, add to the array each time you submit, and then have code to echo all the array items (using a loop).

Comment: Thanks for showing concern, please can you write example please... I'm just a beginner, and do i need Database to run this?  Thanks Waiting to hear from you..

Comment: You need a database or file if you want different users to see the names entered by other users. You can use a session variable if the user should only see their names.

Comment: You can find tutorials about how to use the Session or a database, as per your preference. The best way to learn is to make an attempt. Now you know the basic approach,  you can try something, and update your post if you get stuck

Comment: Thanks.. Please i need a code sample... Thanks I appreciate you

Comment: @ADyson thanks alot... But i don't mind if you can write sample code for me...

Comment: Your code does exactly what you designed it to do.  As suggested by Barmar and ADyson, there are plenty of tutorials on storing things in a database, file or cache.  Stackoverflow is designed for questions that have answers, not open ended "Show me how to do ....." something.

Comment: Closed the question because it really isn't clear what you're trying to do. Commenters have pointed out that you need to _store_ the names somewhere so that you can retrieve them on the next request because HTTP, by its very nature is stateless, won't remember what the previous request(s) sent. You need to decide _where_ you want to store those names. Your options are: in a session (see answer below), in a text file (aka flat file), a database (MySQL, Mongo etc), or more exotic options like an external API. Data in sessions are only available to the user who created the session.

Comment: My suggestion would be to start with sessions are they're fundamentally just arrays, then move on to something more complicated like flat files or databases. Each one has many concepts unto itself and will take time to understand. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This example uses a session. You don't need anything external other than a working PHP installation. I've added comments in the code, but the basic flow is,

- start a session
- read the names from the session. If this is a new session, default the names to an empty array
- read the submitted name
- append the submitted name to the existing names
- write the existing names to the session

```html
<form action="bot.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

```php
<?php

// Always start the session
session_start();

// Check if the form was submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // Read the existing names from the session. Default to an empty array if none are set
    $existingNames = $_SESSION['names'] ?? [];

    // Grab the submitted name
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    // Add it to the end of the list
    $existingNames[] = $name;
  
    // Overwrite the entire session's list
    $_SESSION['names'] = $existingNames;
  
    // Output something interesting
    echo 'Welcome ' . $name;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'There are ' . count($existingNames) . 'name(s).';
    echo '<br>';

    foreach ($existingNames as $storedName) {
        echo $storedName;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer to a question that wasn't asked.  I'm not sure in what case a solution like this would be valuable.  Not your fault, but using a session for something like this is misleading.  Of course we don't know what the OP is actual trying to figure out, but showing the use of sessions certainly isn't of more value than showing how to persist the data into a mysql or postgresql db, or flat files, and I wouldn't encourage anyone to code up those examples, even though they could be done simply.

Comment: @waterloomatt Thanks, I really appreciate you .. I'll try this and get back to you... You the Boss.. God bless

Comment: _Edit_ your question and add the details there. Don't post code into comments.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that.. I hope i see some help now.. Thanks...

Comment: Fyi, I updated my answer to output the stored names.

Comment: Thanks @waterloomatt I appreciate you.. I'll try the code and get back... Thanks..